# jquery fullcalendar: JSON data not loading in any browser except FF3

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I've got a fullcalendar set up on the following url: http://www.forumtheatrebillingham.co.uk/show-calendar.html

It had been working fine, but now something has gone wrong and the data returned by my JSON feed isn't being displayed in the calendar in any browser except FF3.

There are no javascript errors being displayed and monitoring the ajax requests in a console shows them being correctly fetched when the next/last month buttons are pressed.

I'm at a loss to explain why it's not working, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: its working in chrome and FF 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. If you run your response through [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com), you'll see an error on all of your objects

```
{ 
    "title" : "",
    "start" : "2011-10-23",
    "end" : "1970-01-01",
    "pagetitle" : "Songs from the Movie Sister Act",
    "url" : "songs-from-the-movie-sister-act.html",
    "description" : "Mother Superior and the Sisters give an energetic must-see performance. All the hit songs from the two Sister Act movies are included in this show!",
    "image" : "/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/assets_images_shows_Sister Act Artwork.pdf.cdb9fc59e31e0ea8b7440e2a0a1de8e8.jpeg",
    "dates" : "23rd Oct 2011",
    "color": "green",
} ,
```

Since `color` is the last item in the list, it should not be followed by a comma.